# Compiling PHP extensions on Linux

Tags: php, centos, centos6

I need to add a new extension to my PHP 5.5.3.

In the initial installation, I just used `./configure --prefix /usr/local/php-5.5.3` along with `make & make install`. However, I know need to add some of the extensions which I did not configure at the beginning.

Going through a repository is not an option because I have PHP 5.3 running as default and my web server allows multiple PHP configurations at the same time, so I need to know how to install the extensions that come with PHP. I have tried setting extension=mysqli.so in php.ini but no results. I need to compile this from source code.

As I say, going through a repository is not an option.

```
Package php-mysql-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 already installed and latest version.
```

I need **5.5.3**.

Comment: which Linux flavor do you have? I would simply do `yum install php-mysqli` etc and restart apache and game on, on RHEL

Comment: I am using RHEL/CentOS 6. As I said, PHP 5.3 is already installed on the server from a repository, I am compiling 5.5.3 from source. I am not sure whether yum repo will be compatible and accessible. 5.5.3 is not even in the repo last time I checked.

Comment: why don't you using **[XAMPP For Linux](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html)**?